# Few users cant see the Top navigation bar in SPS2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, navigation, user, access

Even though the user has the permission to access the site and they can view other content on the SPS 2013 homepage. Not sure why few users cant see the TOP navigation bar.

I have logging with my credentials from there machine and it works fine.
Its only happening when the user logs with their credentials. So far it seems a credentials issue, but wondering what more to enabled apart from allowing them to access the intranet and that is what they have it as can access the homepage and view other content on the homepage.

Comment: sounds like you have something not published, have you made master page changes that would alter the top nav in any way?

Comment: Yes, master page has been changed vias SPD2013 and saved / published. I guess its expected to modify the master page when you want to do branding to your site.

Wondering what have I miss for the user cant see the top navigation?

Comment: You must then check it in, publish it as a major version, and set it's content approval status to Approved in order for the changes to be reflected for normal users. And master page modification is becoming out of practice, there are much better ways to brand/customize

Comment: Its already published and if I go back to seattle.master gives me option to check out, so the document is published. any other suggestions?

Comment: Is it showing as Approved?

Comment: I don't think added any workflow to approve, how can I verify?

Comment: @EricAlexander any other suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Please check below things:

1. You have not set target audience for the top navigation bar
2. In Master Page, if you have used SPSecurityTrim Control then it's permission and scope
3. Try to give same privileges as you are having to the user who face same issue.

Let me know outputs of all above steps to understand your issue.

Comment: in the past it was working fine, it happened suddenly and no change on the master page level with respect to SPsecurity TRIM control. Wondering if we need to still look at it. Moreover, issue is only for few users and not all.

Comment: Could you please try to grant same permission as you have on site and check that top navigation is showing or not?

Comment: Interesting update, create a new permission group and added a test account. Later started giving permission from Read only to Full control and here is the recent.

Permission - http://imgur.com/Oy23LMU

Any recommendation?

Comment: Hmm, as per your screenshot, it's clearly mentioned that Read Only user doesn't have access on Top Navigation. That's the main root cause of the issue that User having Read Only Permission can't be able to see the Top Navigation in your intranet site.

Comment: Please check in the screenshot, 2nd and 3rd scenario. It doesnt works with full permission too.

Comment: As per SharePoint, it's clearly mentioned, Full Control user also not able to seen the Top Navigation so now it's very difficult to find the root cause or reproduce the same issue in other environment.